# The most concise way to test zero on time.Time

Tags: time, go

I have a struct that may not set a time.Time value on one of its fields. When testing for nullity, I can't use either nil or 0. time.Unix(0,0) is also not the same. I came up with this:

```
var emptyTime time.Time
if thing.time == emptyTime {
    ...
}
```

But I'd like a solution that saves me a line / temp variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [IsZero](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero)() :

```
if thing.time.IsZero() {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if thing.time == time.Time{} {
        ...
}
```

Comment: `if thing.time == (time.Time{}) { // . . . }`. "A parsing ambiguity arises when a composite literal using the TypeName form of the LiteralType appears between the keyword and the opening brace of the block of an "if", "for", or "switch" statement, because the braces surrounding the expressions in the literal are confused with those introducing the block of statements. To resolve the ambiguity in this rare case, the composite literal must appear within parentheses." [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

Comment: Please, at least describe what you’re showing off. Just throwing a block of code out there is probably not suitably elaborative for the less experienced/knowledgeable in go.